# Ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Two things concerning the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$:

- Identify a subset of $R$ that is a subring of $R$ but not an ideal of $R$.
- Identify a maximal ideal in $R$.

For the first part, how about $\{(0,0), (3,5)\}$? It is a subring but $(3,5)(2,5)=(0,5)$ so it is not an ideal.

Secondly, how about $\{(a,b)\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}_6\land b\in\mathbb{Z}_{10}\land a,b\in O\}$, where $O$ is the set of even integers. Is this a maximal ideal of $R$?

Can anyone correct me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: A subring must be closed under multiplication.

Comment: Why isn't this closed?

Comment: @James please explain why

Comment: $(3,5)^2=(9,25)=(3,5)$. No?

Comment: @James also "this" is *very* ambiguous. i thought you meant the question

Comment: Sorry about that. It appears I can't edit my comment. I still think {(0,0),(3,5)} is closed, as $(2,5)$ is not in this subring.

Comment: @James sorry about missing the $(0,0)$. you're right. it's closed hence a subring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you form a subset by repeatedly adding $(1,1)$ to itself then you get a subring of cardinality $\text{lcm}(6,10) = 30$. But $(1,1)$ is the unity in $R$ so the only ideal which contains $(1,1)$ is the whole ring. So this subring is not an ideal. <strike>Also, turns out your example is correct.</strike> A subring must contain the unity of the containing ring, so your example is not a subring.
- Your example is correct.

It looks like you understand this.

Comment: Thanks for the extra example in the first part. I found that insightful. If you want, I just posted [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261361/ring-homomorphism-and-ideal-question-concerning-the-ring-mathbbz-6-times-mat) about the ring considered in my last two posted questions. Only if you're interested. :) Thanks again!

Comment: @riddler Actually, a subring has to contain the unity in the ring, so no ideal is a subring unless it's the whole ring. In which case, your first example was not a subring.